The second variation of an energy functional with two variables
I am considering the second variation of the following energy functional:
$$ I\left( w,\eta\right) = \int _{\Omega }\dfrac{1}{2}\left| \nabla w \right| ^{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}w^{2}\left| \nabla \eta +\xi\right|  ^{2}+\dfrac{\lambda }{4}\left( w_{0}^{2}-w^{2}\right) ^{2}dx
$$
I calculated it as follows, by computing the term $  I\left( w+\epsilon z,\eta+\epsilon\zeta\right) $ and focusing on the terms with coefficients of $\epsilon^2 $:
$$
\int _{\Omega }\left| \nabla z \right| ^{2}+w^{2}\left| \nabla \zeta \right|  ^{2}+4wz\nabla\zeta(\nabla\eta+\xi)+z^2\left| \nabla\eta+\xi \right|^2+\lambda z^2(3w^2-w_0^2) dx
$$
However, in Hirano's paper, it is stated that the second variation of the energy functional can be decomposed as
$$
\int_{\Omega}\left| \nabla z \right| ^{2}+ z^2\left| \nabla\eta+\xi \right|^2+\lambda z(3(z+w_0)^2-w_0^2)dx + \int_{\Omega}w^{2}\left| \nabla \zeta \right|  ^{2} dx+\int_{\Omega}2wz^2\left| \nabla\zeta \right|^2 dx.
$$
.This result differs slightly from my own calculations.
I have recalculated several times, but I have not been able to match the result presented in the paper.
Did I make a mistake in my calculations? If there is a way to reconcile my results with those in the paper, I would greatly appreciate any guidance.

Your calculations seem to be fine. The expressions in the paper cannot be second derivatives as directions $(z, \zeta)$ do not appear quadratically,

The formula cannot be the second variation of anything. E.g., the map
$$
B(z, \zeta) :=\int_\Omega 2wz^2 | \nabla \zeta|^2
$$
does not satisfy
$$
B(tz, t\zeta) = t^2 B(z,\zeta).
$$
Same goes for $\lambda z( z^2 - 2zw_0)$.

Thank you very much. I feel relieved to know that my calculations are correct. I will consider whether the equation is a typographical error in the paper or if the variables have been transformed in some way within the paper.
